# Is there a "native" way to convert from numbers to dB in Tcl

Tags: tcl

dB or [decibel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) is a unit that is used to show ratio in logarithmic scale, and specifecly, the definition of dB that I'm interested in is X(dB) = 20log(x) where x is the "normal" value, and X(dB) is the value in dB. When wrote a code converted between mil. and mm, I noticed that if I use the direct approach, i.e., multiplying by the ratio between the units, I got small errors on the opposite conversion, i.e.: `to_mil [to_mm val_in_mil]` wasn't equal to `val_in_mil` and the same with mm. The library [units](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/units.html) has solved this problem, as the conversions done by it do not have that calculation error. But the specifically doesn't offer (or I didn't find) the option to convert a number to dB in the library.

Is there another library / command that can transform numbers to dB and dB to numbers without calculation errors?

I did an experiment with using the direct math conversion, and I what I got is:

```
>> set a 0.005
0.005
>> set b [expr {20*log10($a)}]
-46.0205999133
>> expr {pow(10,($b/20))}
0.00499999999999
```

Answer (score 4):

It's all a matter of precision. We often tend to forget that floating point numbers are not real numbers (in the mathematical sense of ℝ).

How many decimal digit do you need?

If you, for example, would only need 5 decimal digits, rounding 0.00499999999999 will give you 0.00500 which is what you wanted.

Since rounding fp numbers is not an easy task and may generate even more troubles, you might just change the way you determine if two numbers are equal:

```
 >> set a 0.005
 0.005
 >> set b [expr {20*log10($a)}]
 -46.0205999133
 >> set c [expr {pow(10,($b/20))}]
 0.00499999999999
 >> expr {abs($a - $c) < 1E-10}
 1
 >> expr {abs($a - $c) < 1E-20}
 0
 >> expr {$a - $c}
 8.673617379884035e-19
```

The numbers in your examples can be considered "equal" up to an error or 10<sup>-18</sup>. Note that this is just a rough estimate, not a full solution.

If you're really dealing with problems that are sensitive to numerical errors propagation you might look deeper into "numerical analysis". The article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or, even better, this site: [http://floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/) might be a start.

In case you need a larger precision you should drop your "native" requirement.

You may use the BigFloat offered by tcllib (http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/bigfloat.html or even use GMP (the GNU multiple precision arithmetic library) through ffidl ([http://elf.org/ffidl](http://elf.org/ffidl/)). There's an interface already defined for it: [gmp.tcl](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-87/tcl_ext/ffidl/ffidl/demos/other/gmp.tcl)

Answer (score 1):

With the way floating point numbers are stored, every log10(...) can't correspond to exactly one pow(10, ...). So you lose precision, just like the integer divisions 89/7 and 88/7 both are 12.

When you put a value into floating point format, you should forget the ability to know it's exact value anymore *unless you keep the old, exact value too*. If you want exactly 1/200, store it as the integer 1 and the integer 200. If you want exactly the ten-logarithm of 1/200, store it as 1, 200 and the info that a ten-logarithm has been done on it.

You can fill your entire memory with the first x decimal digits of the square root of 2, but it still won't be the square root of 2 you store.